# How to setup pam on debian 11

Tags: debian, openvpn, authentication, pam, nsswitch.conf

I have installed debian 11 and pam-ldapd.
Now, I want to setup authenticating for openvpn with pam. When I wanted to test it with 'getent passwd' command, I got only local users response.

Can you help me please, how to setup it?

My nsswitch is here:

```
passwd:         files systemd ldap
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

nslcd.conf here

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://10.1.4.113/
base dc=example,dc=eu
#binddn cn=vpnbind,ou=MyUsers,dc=test,dc=net
#binddn vpnadmin@example.eu
binddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=eu
bindpw secret
scope sub

base   group  dc=example,dc=eu
base   passwd dc=example,dc=eu
base   shadow dc=example,dc=eu

bind_timelimit 30
timelimit 30

filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=dc=example,dc=eu))
map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName

filter shadow (&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=example,dc=eu))
map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName


tls_reqcert never
```

Thanks for any answer